# meaning of “ what though “

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have been reading Poe’s Poetry, and, in one or two poems of his, noticed that he uses “ What though “ which I could not figure its meaning out, As here for instance : Poem [ A Dream ]

> **What though** that light,  thro' storm and night,
> So trembled from afar—
> What could there be more purely bright
> In Truth's day-star?

Any help?

Comment: Does it help if you add commas, like this: "*What, though, that light...*"

Comment: [What does it matter {if}](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_though). [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%20though), too

Comment: @mcalex I think that's it. Why not write an answer citing those references?

Comment: You could replace it with _even if..._

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

"What though" is an idiom that in its modern usage means "supposing it true that".

Poe intends to say "even granting that".

Comment: While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].